# Each of my Time Machine backup is over 100MB

Tags: macos, terminal, backup, time-machine

And when I run `tmutil compare` in the terminal, RIGHT after the latest backup is complete, it just start spitting every single file in my system:

```
!         (xattrs)              /.vol
! 8.0K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC/Scripting.localized/Sample Scripts.localized/.DS_Store
! 6.0K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC/Scripting.localized/Sample Scripts.localized/AppleScript.localized/.DS_Store
! 1.2M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/VAqua3-1.jar
! 5.4K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/alpn-api-1.1.3.v20160715.jar
! 608.3K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52.jar
! 2.8M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar
! 53.4K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/boot/alpn-boot-8.1.9.v20160720.charles.jar
! 3.8K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/boot/charles-patch-1.0.jar
! 211.7K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/bounce-0.20.jar
! 1.1M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/flying-saucer-core-9.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
! 224.3K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/gson-2.6.2.jar
! 28.6K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/hpack-v1.0.1.jar
! 31.1K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/image4j-0.7.jar
! 126.2K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/jasypt-1.9.2.jar
! 392.8K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/jcifs-1.3.17.jar
! 575.5K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/joda-time-2.7.jar
! 63.4K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/json-20140107.jar
! 226.0K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/jsyntaxpane-0.9.4.jar
! 104.2K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/miglayout-core-5.1-CHARLES1.jar
! 21.9K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/miglayout-swing-5.1-CHARLES1.jar
! 199.5K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/org.eclipse.egit.github.core-2.1.5.jar
! 582.7K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar
! 2.3M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/quaqua-9.4.2.jar
! 1.1M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/rhino-1.7R5.jar
! 95.4K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/servlet-api-2.4.jar
! 75.9K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/swing-layout-1.0.jar
! 16.7K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/webp-imageio-1.0.jar
! 7.0K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
! 24.4K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
! 526.2K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Java/xstream-1.4.8.jar
! 3.0M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar
! 3.7M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
! 8.1K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
! 43.5K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
! 1.1M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
! 1.9M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
! 37.3K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
! 255.5K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
! 233.5K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
! 67.3K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
! 93.4K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar
! 630.2K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar
! 380B    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
! 3.3M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar
! 62.3M   (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar
! 3.0K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
! 3.0K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Charles.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_113.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
! 3.5M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/charsets.jar
! 8.7K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
! 537.5K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/ext/localedata.jar
! 13.1K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunec.jar
! 185.4K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
! 224.0K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
! 67.2K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
! 90.2K   (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar
! 569.4K  (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/jsse.jar
! 2.4M    (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/resources.jar
! 58.8M   (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/rt.jar
! 2.4K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
! 2.4K    (xattrs)              /Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/MacOS/Runtime.jre/Contents/Home/lib/security/local_policy.jar
! 17.6K   (xattrs)              /Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/COPYING
! 115.2K  (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl
! 130B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Growl.h
! 33.6K   (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GrowlApplicationBridge-Carbon.h
! 26.8K   (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GrowlApplicationBridge.h
! 15.4K   (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GrowlDefines.h
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
! 878B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/Headers/NSData+AES.h
! 486B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/Headers/NSData+AESKey.h
! 485B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/Headers/NSData+AESValue.h
! 429B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/Headers/NSMutableData+AES.h
! 46.6K   (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/NSData+AES
! 92B     (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/NSData+AES.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
! 867B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKBreakpoint.h
! 1.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKGutterView.h
! 890B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKSyntaxHighlighter.h
! 3.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKTextView.h
! 1016B   (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKTrigger.h
! 1.5K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKUtils.h
! 309B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKView.h
! 3.1K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OKViewController.h
! 321B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/OkudaKit.h
! 852.6K  (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/OkudaKit
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
! 869B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/applescript.css
! 846B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/c.css
! 18.1K   (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/c.grammar
! 745B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/css.css
! 92B     (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
! 5.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/en.lproj/OKViewController.nib
! 518B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/html.css
! 2.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/html.grammar
! 728B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/js.css
! 854B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/json.css
! 1.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/py.css
! 1.5K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/tdtemplateengine.grammar
! 736B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/templateengine.css
! 869B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/unix.css
! 518B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/xquery.css
! 6.5K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/OkudaKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/xquery.grammar
! 1.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PEGKit.h
! 1.6K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKAST.h
! 3.8K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKAssembly.h
! 4.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKCommentState.h
! 2.6K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKDelimitState.h
! 1.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKEmailState.h
! 1.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKHashtagState.h
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKMultiLineCommentState.h
! 3.0K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKNumberState.h
! 5.3K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKParser+Subclass.h
! 3.0K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKParser.h
! 2.6K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKQuoteState.h
! 2.8K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKReader.h
! 1.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKRecognitionException.h
! 1.3K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKSingleLineCommentState.h
! 3.0K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKSymbolState.h
! 7.8K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKToken.h
! 6.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKTokenizer.h
! 3.1K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKTokenizerState.h
! 1.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKTwitterState.h
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKTypes.h
! 1.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKURLState.h
! 2.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKWhitespaceState.h
! 2.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PKWordState.h
! 202.6K  (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/PEGKit
! 1.1K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
! 202B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PEGKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
! 881B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/NSBezierPath_AMShading.h
! 976B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PSMAdiumTabStyle.h
! 673B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PSMOverflowPopUpButton.h
! 3.1K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PSMTabBarCell.h
! 8.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PSMTabBarControl.h
! 1.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PSMTabStyle.h
! 233.5K  (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/PSMTabBarControl
! 851B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/32x32_log.png
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/32x32cancel.png
! 93B     (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AdiumGradient.png
! 292B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabCloseDirty_Front.png
! 292B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabCloseDirty_Front_Pressed.png
! 297B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabCloseDirty_Front_Rollover.png
! 307B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabClose_Front.png
! 310B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabClose_Front_Pressed.png
! 317B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabClose_Front_Rollover.png
! 371B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabNew.png
! 380B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabNewPressed.png
! 380B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabNewRollover.png
! 380B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabsBackground.png
! 192B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabsDown.png
! 240B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabsDownGraphite.png
! 182B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabsDownNonKey.png
! 159B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabsSeparator.png
! 175B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AquaTabsSeparatorDown.png
! 1.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
! 327B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabClose_Dirty.png
! 320B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabClose_Dirty_Pressed.png
! 320B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabClose_Dirty_Rollover.png
! 309B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabClose_Front.png
! 310B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabClose_Front_Pressed.png
! 308B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabClose_Front_Rollover.png
! 380B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabNewMetal.png
! 380B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabNewMetalPressed.png
! 384B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TabNewMetalRollover.png
! 256B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/overflowImage.png
! 250B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/overflowImagePressed.png
! 564B    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/PSMTabBarControl.framework/Versions/A/Resources/pi.png
! 1.5K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Info.plist
! 175.5K  (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/MacOS/Autoupdate
! 8B      (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/PkgInfo
! 152.1K  (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/AppIcon.icns
! 6.4K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/SUStatus.nib
! 7.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/ar.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 6.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/ca.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 7.3K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/cs.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 7.8K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/da.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 7.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 7.2K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/el.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 8.9K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Sparkle.strings
! 7.6K    (GID)                 /Applications/Fluid.app/Contents/Resources/FluidApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Autoupdate.app/Contents/Resources/es.lproj/Sparkle.strings
```

And if I let it initiate the backup on it's own, an hour later, it will easily get over 1GB.

To clarify, right after the backup is complete, when run `tmutil compare` I expect to see zero updated files. Consequently, the backup size should be zero.

Or, in the other scenario where I let it run the backup on it's own, after an hour, I expect `tmutil compare` to spit only the files I've edited. So, the backup size after an hour of development should be less than 10MB, and not over 1GB.

Some pointers please?

Comment: Could you clarify the issue? AFAIK this is the default behaviour of time machine. Are you hoping to perform a more selective backup?

Comment: @Scottmeup updated it. Thanx.

Comment: What do you mean by "I let it run the backup on it's own"?

Comment: Things happen while the backup is actually backing up files.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen There seems to be rather a lot to happen here...

Comment: @nohillside If I don't initiate the backup by pressing `Back Up Now` it's going to run on it's own on an hourly interval. That's what I mean by "on it's own".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen true, but not 100MB worth of changes.

Comment: Could you try using [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/)?

Comment: I found that just running `tmutil compare` sometimes doesn't compare the versions you would expect it to compare (among others it showed me the content of `/sbin` as changed, a directory which is protected by SIP). What happens if you run `tmutil compare "$(tmutil latestbackup)"` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I would exclude those noisy apps that are storing configuration data in the application bundle. Even if you exclude them and all /Applications on a temporary basis, you can get a clean, small backup and know things are ok. Then you can see if these apps have an update or the developer can help and choose to exclude portions of them or live with their messy habits.

You can install Mac apps in other places and perhaps have a messy apps folder and put an alias to them in /Applications and exclude their folder long term.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work. I know you only see Charles, Cyberduck and Fluid in the question, but that's just an excerpt of the `tmutil compare` output. If I let it run, you'll see all possible apps, and then it'll just keep on running. I know it makes no sense. But I don't even know how to approach this. I'm trying BackupLoupe now.. let's see..

Comment: How will excluding /Applications entirely not work to see if that’s causing the slow @Birowsky ?